# Sequence Vs Auto increment

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I understood why do i use Sequence when i want to auto increment, however, why do i have to do all that setting when using postgresql. in mysql all that i have to do is diclear that the field will be primary key and AutoIncrement and the job done. in Spring boot Java and postgres i need to create a lot of setting

for example the code bellow. can someone please help me understand why do i have to go through all this long process.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "owner_sequence",
        sequenceName ="owner_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = SEQUENCE,
        generator = "owner_sequence"
)
```

Comment: A sequence is a different database object, just like a table, view, function or whatever. Same in Oracle, SQL Server and many other databases.

Comment: A column defined as `generated by default as identity` (or better `generated always as identity`) behaves the same as an `auto_increment` in MySQL. There should be no reason to configure the sequence separately.

Comment: Still dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

In short, sequences gives a more flexibility. Backside - writing more code. Sequences are useful when developing non trivial, complex projects like replication systems. Sequences are nice when you will need manual management of your "id" fields numbering and allows to automate many things in database.

Some usage example:

```
create sequence test_id_seq;
create table test(field1 int not null default nextval('test_id_seq'));

ALTER SEQUENCE test_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
UPDATE t SET idcolumn=nextval('test_id_seq');
```